# Taking expectations for Fisher information/Jeffreys' prior

Tags: bayesian, prior, fisher-information

I've been working through a few examples of the Jeffreys' prior; however, I'm a little confused by one section. I was hoping that somebody could provide some clarification.

If the Jeffreys' prior is defined as:

$$ \pi_{j}(\theta) = \sqrt{I(\theta)} $$

where $I(\theta) = {\bf E}\left[\left(\frac{\partial\text{log}p(x_{i}|\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right)^2\right] = -{\bf E}\left[\frac{\partial\text{log}p(x_{i}|\theta)^{2}}{\partial\theta}\right]$

Then, for $p(x_{i}|\theta) \sim Bin(k,\theta)$ with ${\bf E}[X] = k\theta$,

Step 1:

$$ {\bf E}\left[\frac{\partial\text{log}p(x_{i}|\theta)^{2}}{\partial\theta}\right] = - \frac{k}{\theta} - \frac{k}{(1-\theta)^{2}} +\frac{k\theta}{(1-\theta)^{2}} = \frac{k(\theta-1)}{\theta(1-\theta)^{2}} $$

Now, for the example that I've been looking at, it states that:

Step 2:

$$ -{\bf E}\left[\frac{\partial\text{log}p(x_{i}|\theta)^{2}}{\partial\theta}\right] = \frac{k}{\theta(1-\theta)} $$

How is this step achieved? Obviously can't we just put a minus sign on the result from Step 1 to yield:

Step 1:

$$ {\bf E}\left[\frac{\partial\text{log}p(x_{i}|\theta)^{2}}{\partial\theta}\right] = - \frac{k}{\theta} - \frac{k}{(1-\theta)^{2}} +\frac{k\theta}{(1-\theta)^{2}} = \frac{k(\theta-1)}{\theta(1-\theta)^{2}} $$

Step 2:

$$ -{\bf E}\left[\frac{\partial\text{log}p(x_{i}|\theta)^{2}}{\partial\theta}\right] = - \left( - \frac{k}{\theta} - \frac{k}{(1-\theta)^{2}} +\frac{k\theta}{(1-\theta)^{2}} \right) = -\frac{k(\theta-1)}{\theta(1-\theta)^{2}} $$

Comment: Actually, we *can* put a minus sign on the result from step 1... note that $-(\theta-1) = (1-\theta)$, and you can cancel out the exponent in the denominator's $(1-\theta)$.  (It happens to the best of us sometimes.)

Comment: That's pretty embarrassing. I appreciate your help (and your not making me feel too bad for not picking up on that). It's been one of those days. Thanks!